# Is it possible to make files unsearchable in Windows 10 (64-bit)?

Tags: windows

Is it possible to hide all the files inside a folder with just doing the steps only to the parent folder. [Because I think this step](http://windows.mercenie.com/windows-xp/create-hidden-unsearchable-file-folder/), I need to repeat the steps for every file inisde the parent folder. So if I have 50 files wanted to be hidden inside the parent folder. I have to do the same steps 50 times for all the files inside the parent folder.

Comment: I haven't tested, but can't you simply use a wildcard? attrib +s +h C:\directory\* -- this should (assuming wildcard is possible) apply that attributes to all files inside that folder.

Answer (score 0):

Check the help:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>attrib /?
Displays or changes file attributes.

ATTRIB [+R | -R] [+A | -A ] [+S | -S] [+H | -H] [+I | -I]
       [drive:][path][filename] [/S [/D] [/L]]

  +   Sets an attribute.
  -   Clears an attribute.
  R   Read-only file attribute.
  A   Archive file attribute.
  S   System file attribute.
  H   Hidden file attribute.
  I   Not content indexed file attribute.
  X   No scrub file attribute.
  V   Integrity attribute.
  [drive:][path][filename]
      Specifies a file or files for attrib to process.
  /S  Processes matching files in the current folder
      and all subfolders.
  /D  Processes folders as well.
  /L  Work on the attributes of the Symbolic Link versus
      the target of the Symbolic Link
```

so obviously wildcards do the job, like "ATTRIB +H +S C:\DIR\*.*", and you can also use /S to apply it to a whole tree

Comment: Please teach me step-by-step. Can't find tutorials for wildcard hiding method.

Comment: If you cannot do it with the instructions in the answer, this is not something you should do anyway. You might wreck your whole machine.